# React onClick event button - class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, buttonclick

happy 2022!
I'm working on adding an onClick event listener/button.
This app it's an Airbnb clone, and I'm working on the SingleRoom page, which displays details about that specific room/home.
Once the user clicks to a particular place, it will redirect to the SingleRoom page (below code) it has a "Reserve now" button so the user can pay for the room/home.

When I try adding the button, I get this error:
**Uncaught Error: SingleRoom(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.**

The reserve button will open a modal to either cancel or continue to make the payment.

Would you please help me in making the code work?
Thank you

**Updated the code.. It now has the else statement**
But it throws this error:
**Line 29:15:  'setOpenModal' is not defined  no-undef**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import defaultBcg from "../images/room-1.jpeg";
import Banner from "../components/Banner";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { RoomContext } from "../context";
import StyledHero from "../components/StyledHero";
import "../components/Modal.css";

export default class SingleRoom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { slug: this.props.match.params.slug, defaultBcg };
  }

  static contextType = RoomContext;
  render() {
    const { getRoom } = this.context;
    const room = getRoom(this.state.slug);
    if (!room) {
      return (
        <div className="error">
          <h3>Sorry we couldn't find the room you were looking for'...</h3>
          <Link to="/rooms" className="btn-primary">
            Back to rooms
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    }else{
        Modal(setOpenModal);
    }

function Modal({ setOpenModal }) {
  const {
      name,
      description,
      capacity,
      size,
      price,
      extras,
      breakfast,
      pets,
      images,
    } = room;

    const [mainImg, ...defaultImg] = images;
      return (
        <>
          <StyledHero img={mainImg || this.state.defaultBcg}>
            <Banner title={`${name}`}></Banner>
          </StyledHero>
          <section className="single-room">
            <div className="single-room-images">
              {defaultImg.map((item, index) => {
                return <img key={index} src={item} alt={name} />;
              })}
            </div>
            <div className="single-room-info">
              <article className="desc">
                <h3>details</h3>
                <p>{description}</p>
              </article>
              <article className="info">
                <h3>Info</h3>
                <h6>Price: ${price}</h6>
                <h6>Size: ${size} SQFT</h6>
                <h6>
                  Max capacity: {""}
                  {capacity > 1 ? `${capacity} people` : `${capacity} person`}
                </h6>
                <h6>{pets ? "pets allowed" : "no pets allowed"}</h6>
                <h6>{breakfast && "free breakfast included"}</h6>

                <div className="modalBackground">
                  <div className="modalContainer">
                    <div className="titleCloseBtn">
                      <button
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpenModal(false);
                        }}
                      >
                        X
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="title">
                      <h1>Reservation details</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="body">
                      <p>
                      Total amount {{price}}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer">
                      <button
                        onClick={() => {
                          setOpenModal(false);
                        }}
                        id="cancelBtn"
                      >
                        Cancel
                      </button>
                      <button>Reserve Now</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section className="room-extras">
            <h6>extras</h6>
            <ul className="extras">
              {extras.map((item, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>- {item}</li>;
              })}
            </ul>
          </section>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only returning JSX when there is no room `if (!room) {`. If there is a room you're not returning anything.

Comment: That code might work but your implementation of that code doesn't work which is why you're getting that error. You're not returning anything if `room` exists.

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  I can see that now. What would be an easy way to fix this?

Comment: You can return the modal part in else scope.

Comment: I suppose I would first think about whether I'm using class components or function components. For modals I would [look into portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). There is not "reserve" button in your code so I can't really see how that's meant to work.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no else condition found. Change your code to

```
render() {
        const { getRoom } = this.context;
        const room = getRoom(this.state.slug);
        if (!room) {
          return (
            <div className="error">
              <h3>Sorry we couldn't find the room you were looking for'...</h3>
              <Link to="/rooms" className="btn-primary">
                Back to rooms
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        }else{
            Modal(setOpenModal);
        }
    }

function Modal({ setOpenModal }) {
      const {
          name,
          description,
          capacity,
          size,
          price,
          extras,
          breakfast,
          pets,
          images,
        } = room;
    
        const [mainImg, ...defaultImg] = images;
          return (
            <>
              <StyledHero img={mainImg || this.state.defaultBcg}>
                <Banner title={`${name}`}></Banner>
              </StyledHero>
              <section className="single-room">
                <div className="single-room-images">
                  {defaultImg.map((item, index) => {
                    return <img key={index} src={item} alt={name} />;
                  })}
                </div>
                <div className="single-room-info">
                  <article className="desc">
                    <h3>details</h3>
                    <p>{description}</p>
                  </article>
                  <article className="info">
                    <h3>Info</h3>
                    <h6>Price: ${price}</h6>
                    <h6>Size: ${size} SQFT</h6>
                    <h6>
                      Max capacity: {""}
                      {capacity > 1 ? `${capacity} people` : `${capacity} person`}
                    </h6>
                    <h6>{pets ? "pets allowed" : "no pets allowed"}</h6>
                    <h6>{breakfast && "free breakfast included"}</h6>
    
                    <div className="modalBackground">
                      <div className="modalContainer">
                        <div className="titleCloseBtn">
                          <button
                            onClick={() => {
                              setOpenModal(false);
                            }}
                          >
                            X
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="title">
                          <h1>Reservation details</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="body">
                          <p>
                          Total amount {{price}}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="footer">
                          <button
                            onClick={() => {
                              setOpenModal(false);
                            }}
                            id="cancelBtn"
                          >
                            Cancel
                          </button>
                          <button>Continue</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </article>
                </div>
              </section>
              <section className="room-extras">
                <h6>extras</h6>
                <ul className="extras">
                  {extras.map((item, index) => {
                    return <li key={index}>- {item}</li>;
                  })}
                </ul>
              </section>
            </>
          );
        }
```

Comment: Do you think `Modal(setOpenModal);` will work given that the Modal function signature is `Modal({ setOpenModal })`?

Comment: Thanks @Hetal. I just tried that and I got this error:

``ERROR in src/pages/SingleRoom.js
  Line 33:9:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (33:9)``

Then I modified the curly braces and got the following error: 
``ERROR in src/pages/SingleRoom.js
  Line 29:15:  'setOpenModal' is not defined  no-undef``

Comment: pass parameter for setOpenModal. I dont know for which purpose you use it so i kept it that way...you can modify it as per your need